# Arduino seems to crash when uint32_t > 45

Tags: c++, arduino

I have the below program running on an Uno clone.

```
uint32_t counter = 0;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    while(!Serial);
}

void loop() {
    char *result = malloc(32);
    sprintf(result, "%024u", counter);

    Serial.print("{\"n\": ");
    Serial.print(result);
    Serial.println(" }");

    delay(100);
    counter++;
}
```

Everything works fine and the string is printed and counter incremented as expected. Below is an example of the output:

```
{"n": 000000000000000000000000 }
{"n": 000000000000000000000001 }
{"n": 000000000000000000000002 }
{"n": 000000000000000000000003 }
....
```

However, every time that `counter > 45`, the program stops printing over UART, here's what the output looks like at this point:

```
{"n": 000000000000000000000044 }
{"n": 000000000000000000000045 }
{"n":  }
```

Any insight as to what could be causing this issue is greatly appreciated.

Comment: where do you `free` the `result `?

Comment: Really should be using `char result[32]` instead

Comment: @Blaze Never, and doing so fixes my issue. Having read up on `free` I understand why now. I'm coming mainly from a Python background so this is all new to me. Cheers

Comment: @Kerndog73 what are the pros and cons of using `malloc` vs `char result[]`?

Comment: @AdamMitchell Maybe I'll write an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each time `loop` is called, 32 bytes of memory is allocated. An Arduino Uno doesn't have much memory so it quickly runs out. You need to deallocate the memory when you're finished using. Here's an analogy.

RAM is a piece of string. This string has a fixed length. You can cut off a piece of this string and use it for whatever you like. This is allocation. If you keep cutting of 32 bytes from your string you'll eventually run out. You need to tape the piece of string back onto the main string when you're finished using it. This is deallocation.

That was a pretty crappy analogy but I hope you got the idea! To solve the immediate problem you can simply append `free(result)` to the end of the function to deallocate every time you allocate. To really solve the problem properly, you should allocate on the stack instead of the heap. When you allocate on the stack, the memory is automatically deallocated at the end of the scope. To allocate 32 bytes on the stack, you would simply do this:

```
char result[32];
```

The memory in `result` is only valid within it's enclosing scope (the `loop` function). The above snippet is basically equivalent to this:

```
char result_0;
char result_1;
char result_2;
// ...
char result_29;
char result_30;
char result_31;
```

Stack allocation is much faster than heap allocation (`malloc` and `free`) because the compiler knows exactly how much memory you're using. This has its downsides though. In order to stack allocate memory, the compiler needs to know how much memory you're using! You can't do this:

```
int size = get_a_number_from_somewhere();
char result[size];
```

because the compiler doesn't know how much memory to allocate. This however:

```
int size = get_a_number_from_somewhere();
char *result = malloc(size);
// ...
free(result);
```

is totally fine.

In general, you should stack allocate when the amount of memory you need is a compile-time constant (e.g. `32`) and heap allocate otherwise. Every time you write `malloc`, think carefully about where the corresponding `free` should go.

Comment: Plz add that he should check if malloc() == NULL

Answer (score 1):

malloc() is allowed, but not very useful on an Arduino with very limited RAM.

An Arduino does not have an operating system, which could interfere if there's not enough memory to allocate. (And what should it do, anyway, to keep the Arduino running forever?)

If you have a Java background, avoid the `new` keyword as well, which causes the same issues.

If you need memory, get it as early as possible (best at compile time) and keep it.

*Of course, the `free(result)` response is correct as well.*

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use `String()`, like the code bellow:

```
uint32_t counter = 0;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    while(!Serial);
}

void loop() {

    Serial.print("{\"n\": ");
    Serial.print(String(counter));
    Serial.println(" }");

    delay(100);
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: Why use String ? `Serial.print(counter);` does exactly what you want.

Comment: I do no... Why are he using a char? My point was, he don't need use char he could use string =p